# Can not save to mongodb from Pyspark

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I try to save to Mongodb with this script but it not working:

```
df_load.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").save()
```

when I run it, the error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(java.lang.Object[])'
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.getOptionsFromConf(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:233)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.getOptionsFromConf(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:113)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.apply(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Version:

```
Spark: 3.4.1
Scala: 2.12
Java 20
```

pyspark config:

```
working_directory = 'D:/jars/*'
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName('ml')\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://localhost:27017/test.spark")\
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://localhost:27017/test.spark")\
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', working_directory).getOrCreate()
```

I can't figure out what causes this, any help ? May the error come from Version ? I tried to decrease the version of pyspark but it still not working.

Hoping a clearly explain from your guys, thank you

Comment: What is `df_load`

Comment: this is dataframe that I have read from my local by pyspark:

df_load = spark.read.csv("D:/dataset/Flat_test_PreProcessed.csv", header=True)

Answer (score 0):

I use wrong jar in the dict:

> mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0
> instead of
> mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.0 because of my scala version is 2.12

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).